# Adding new field in RoR simple-form gives ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

We are looking to add a new hidden field into our form but every time I add in a new field (even copy and pasting a field that works and just adding a number to the end) we get an error,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `hidden_gclid' for #<Wizard::Lead::Step2:0x00000004d859d8>):
```

Please let me know which code you would like to see. I tried reading some documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and thought, I might need to add a database column but I'm not sure.

Thank you all for the help and I apologize for the delay. I didn't receive 
 notification on the comments. I have a new problem though. After getting the new field created we are getting this error,

```
F, [2019-01-09T05:08:28.887941 #26599] FATAL -- : [437ed38a-c36c-4121-9608-385c43d0449e]   
F, [2019-01-09T05:08:28.888395 #26599] FATAL -- : [437ed38a-c36c-4121-9608-385c43d0449e] NameError (undefined local variable or method `hidden_gclid' for #<Lead:0x0000000527c4a0>):
F, [2019-01-09T05:08:28.888449 #26599] FATAL -- : [437ed38a-c36c-4121-9608-385c43d0449e]   
F, [2019-01-09T05:08:28.888487 #26599] FATAL -- : [437ed38a-c36c-4121-9608-385c43d0449e] app/models/lead.rb:91:in `sales_force_info'
```

lead.rb

```
# This model represents an User's (customer) submission through the form
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
  validates :address, :lat, :lng, presence: true

  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :characteristics

  has_many :offers, inverse_of: :lead, dependent: :destroy

  scope :newest_first, (-> { order(created_at: :desc) })

  enum pool_type: %i[
    in_ground above_ground none_or_community
  ]

  enum kitchen_condition: %i[
    great_kitchen typical_kitchen needs_work_kitchen
  ]
  enum bathroom_condition: %i[
    great_bathroom typical_bathroom needs_work_bathroom
  ]

  enum timeline_to_sell: %i[
    asap 2_4_weeks 4_6_weeks few_months just_curious
  ]

  enum looking_for_another: %i[
    yes already_found no
  ]

  enum reasons_for_selling: %i[
    upgrading relocating downsizing retiring selling_investment
  ]

  enum offer_status: %i[
    pending sent accepted declined closed
  ]

  attr_accessor :hidden_gclid  

  def has_basic_information?
    if bedrooms.present? || bathrooms.present? ||
       built_surface.present? || pool_type.present? ||
       kitchen_condition.present? || bathroom_condition.present? ||
       renovated.present? || renovated_spent.present? ||
       renovated_description.present?
      return true
    end

    false
  end

  def street
    (address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").count == 3) ? address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").first : "#{address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").first}, #{address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").second}"
  end

  def city
    address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").second_to_last
  end

  def state_code
    address.remove(', USA')&.split(",").last
  end

  def sales_force_info
    form = { 'oid' => 'xxxxxx', # roganization id
             'retURL' => 'http://placeholder.com',
             '00No0000009e5Lb' => 'Cash Offer',
             'country_code' => 'US',
             'first_name' => user&.first_name,
             'last_name' => user&.last_name,
             'phone' => user&.phone,
             'street' => street, #address
             'city' =>  city,
             'state_code' => state_code,
             'zip' => zip,
             'description' => "Check more lead info at www.placeholder.com/leads/#{id}",
             'email' => user&.email,
             'lead_source' => user&.how_about_us || "Web",
             '00N1N00000Oko3t' => bedrooms,
             '00N1N00000Oko3y' => bathrooms,
             '00N1N00000Oko43' => built_surface,
             '00N1N00000Oko48' => air_conditioner,
             '00N1N00000Oko4N' => roof_age,
             '00N1N00000Oko4h' => timeline_to_sell,
             '00N1N00000Oko4m' => looking_for_another,
             '00N1N00000Oko4r' => reasons_for_selling,
             '00N1N00000Oko4S' => renovated,
             '00N1N00000Oko4X' => renovated_spent,
             '00N1N00000Oko4c' => renovated_description,
             '00N1N00000Oko4w' => own_valuation,
             '00N1N00000PMKAo' => hidden_gclid
            }
    form
  end

  def send_info_to_sales_force
    puts "SENDING INFO TO SALES FORCE!"
    url = URI('https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8')
    form = sales_force_info
    res = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, form)
    puts res.body
  end
end
```

form

```
:javascript
  window.onload = function getGclid() {        
             document.getElementById("00N1N00000PMKAo").value = (name = new RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)gclid=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? name.split(",")[1] : ""; }
.block.block-fill-height.px-0
  = render 'application/header', logo: 'logo-blue.png'
  .container.mt-2.pt-5
    .card.card-outline-primary
      %h3.card-header
        %ul.nav.nav-bordered
          %li.nav-item
            %a.nav-link{:href => "#"} Basics
          %li.nav-item
            %a.nav-link.active{:href => "#"} Sale
          %li.nav-item
            %a.nav-link{:href => "#"} Offer
      .card-block
        %h4.card-title Where should we send your offer?
        %p.card-text
          %strong Save your progress
          and join thousands of home owners who work with us every month.
        %hr
          %h5.mt-5 Create your account below:
          = simple_form_for User.new, url: '/users', method: 'POST', html: { class:'mt-4' } do |f|
            .form-group
              = f.label(:phone, 'Phone')
              = f.input_field(:phone, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Phone', required: true)
            .form-group
              = f.label(:first_name, 'First Name')
              = f.input_field(:first_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name')
            .form-group
              = f.label(:last_name, 'Last Name')
              = f.input_field(:last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name')
            .form-group
              = f.label(:email, 'Email')
              = f.input_field(:email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter your Email')
            .form-group
              = f.label(:password, 'Password')
              = f.input_field(:password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: '6 characters minimum')
            .form-group
              = f.label(:how_about_us, 'Where did you hear about us?')
              %br
              = f.select :how_about_us, ['TV Commercial', 'Word of Mouth', 'Radio', 'Web', 'Letter/Postcard/Doorhanger',
                                     'Social Media', 'Telephone Call'], class: 'form-control', prompt: 'Please Select', required: true
            %hr
              = hidden_field_tag(:hidden_gclid, "", :id => "00N1N00000PMKAo")
              = hidden_field_tag(:current_step, 'step3')
              = f.submit 'Next', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg'
```

It looks like we have the form going without any errors now but we need the hidden field ID 00N1N00000PMKAo to send to salesforce but it isn't.

Comment: Can you post the existing form code and the new field you added?

Comment: I smell a typo. Shouldn't that name be `hidden_gcl_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Since simple_form relies on the model instance you have two options here:

- add a database column to the corresponding table
- use a virtual attribute

Looks like you don't want to store the value in the db, in this case just add `attr_accessor :hidden_gclid` to your model. After it you can use it like a normal attribute inside the controller action.

Comment: i was able to get the field created but now have this error going to the next step of the form (placed error in my initial question)

Comment: @user3706739, could you please add to the question: form code, corresponding model and controller actions code, rails server log with full error stacktrace

Comment: after tinkering around a bit, it looks like i do need to store the value in the database because how this is setup is the email to salesforce pulls the field variables form the DB.

Comment: @user3706739, you've just answered on your own question - you really need to add a new db column to store the value of something strange with name `gclid` :)

Comment: i know ::face-palm.   I have been looking up how to do this but am having an issue creating it.  I thought I was doing it right but it doesn't seem to be working.  What i saw in simple_form was to create it using migrate and I have tried $ rails generate migration AddHiddenGclidToUsers.  (If you couldn't already tell RoR is not my strong suit... )

Comment: @user3706739, yes, you need to add a migration. You can find docs about it in [ROR guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: i don't know if this is frowned upon or allowed in stack or not but is this something we can pay you to do for us?  Looks to be over our head.

Comment: @user3706739, not sure about SO rules for discussing job in comments, but in any case I have enough work right now. Try to find a freelancer on Upwork or any other site